# Understanding / Using __init__ method of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I came across this idea how to make a Python class serializeable.

```
class FileItem(dict):
    def __init__(self, name):
        dict.__init__(self, name=name)

x = FileItem("test")
print(x)

{'name': 'test'}
```

This works fine, but I do not understand how. I thought `dict.__init__` calls the `__init__` method from the dict class to create a new instance and so I expected this to work:

`x = dict.__init__(name="test")`

This results in the following error:

`TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'dict' object needs an argument`

Why is this different to the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, notice that you've not provided a second argument to `__init__`,

```
>>> x = dict.__init__(name="test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'dict' object needs an argument
```

It require the instance, i.e `self`, as the first argument. Of course, if you create an appropriate instance and pass that, `__init__` returns `None`:

```
>>> x = dict.__init__({}, name="test")
>>> print(x)
None
```

Because `__init__` is not a constructor, it is an initializer. In Python these are two distinct steps in the object initialization process.

The "constructor" is `__new__`:

```
>>> dict.__new__(dict)
{}
```

[Read about it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) in the Python data model docs.

Also, for the sake of decency, you probably shouldn't be sprinkling:

```
x = dict.__new__(dict)
```

In real code. But this is how the mechanics of it work. All of this happens in `type.__call__`, by the way. `type` is the parent class that creates classes, a metaclass. (It is also itself a type... `type(type) is type` just like `type(dict) is type`... )

```
>>> type.__call__(dict)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) creates new instances but [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is used for initializing a newly created instance, so `__init__` requires an instance to work with.

When you do `dict.__init__(name='test')` then this isn't operating on any instance, hence the error. With `dict.__init__(self, name=name)` on the other hand, you do pass the instance `self` as an argument and hence it works.

Typically you'd use `super().__init__(name=name)` which takes care of providing `self` as an argument and also works when you decide to changes base classes later on.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the `self` property which isn't passed, the `__init__` property applies its computations on the instance (`self`) passed in, if the `__init__` function doesn't have any context, it throws an error
Have a great day, Lukas.